# How to delete characters from string values of dictionaries in list?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
 litofdict = [{'name': 'Mike', 'surname':'Mikeson', 'age':'15\n'},{'name': 'John', 'surname':'Johnson', 'age':'15\n'},{'name': 'Tomy', 'surname':'Tomson', 'age':'19'}]
```

How to only remove those '\n' only if they are present (which I am not sure how to check) and return a list consisted only from values that "clear from '\n' of dictionary? Thanks :)

```
with open("name.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
        listofdict.append(dict(zip(['name','surname','age']), l.split('|'))))
return listofdict
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through the `dict.items()` and `strip` the values to remove the carriage return, then use a list comprehension to do this for each `dict`

```
>>> [{key: val.strip() for key, val in i.items()} for i in listofdict]
[{'surname': 'Mikeson', 'age': '15', 'name': 'Mike'},
 {'surname': 'Johnson', 'age': '15', 'name': 'John'},
 {'surname': 'Tomson', 'age': '19', 'name': 'Tomy'}]
```

It's hard to say without seeing your file, but you could do this without any postprocessing by adjusting your file reading

```
with open("name.txt") as file:
    listofdict = [dict(zip(['name','surname','age']), l.strip().split('|')) for l in file]
    return listofdict
```

Comment: @HansJohanbach If this answers your question, you may [accept this as a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by selecting the green check mark to the left :)

Comment: Oh I will of course, however it needs to pass 3 minutes :)